# Python: calculating the probability a point will conform to curve

Tags: python, probability

Have a situation where I am given a total ticket count, and cumulative ticket sale data as follows:

```
Total Tickets Available: 300
Day 1: 15 tickets sold to date
Day 2: 20 tickets sold to date
Day 3: 25 tickets sold to date
Day 4: 30 tickets sold to date
Day 5: 46 tickets sold to date
```

The number of tickets sold is nonlinear, and I'm asked if someone plans to buy a ticket on Day 23, what is the probability he will get a ticket?

I've been looking at quite a libraries used for curve fitting like numpy, PyLab, and sage but I've been a bit overwhelmed since statistics is not in my background. How would I easily calculate a probability given this set of data? If it helps, I also have ticket sale data at other locations, the curve should be somewhat different.

Comment: Are you given a lot of such datasets (N tickets, D days per data set)? If so, then you could do some machine learning or genetic algorithms with this

Comment: Initially no, since data collection has not started, but eventually, we suppose maybe 200-250 data points over a three month period, depending on the location. My main problem with implementing machine learning algorithms is that each location is different, so I'm not sure how it will work, also, we are not starting with a lot of data points (actually we are starting with 0). My biggest issue at the moment is somehow drawing a probability out of the data, rather than just finding a regression.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to need a bit more domain knowledge to be able to get a useful answer out of this. What reason do you have to believe it's nonlinear? If you're confident that it's nonlinear, what sort of model would you expect -- quadratic, exponential, logarithmic?

Comment: The reason I know its nonlinear is because dates for ticket sales are "assigned" in a non-linear fashion, and on that assigned date, a person may sign up for a ticket at hundreds of different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer to this question would require more information about the problem--are people more/less likely to buy a ticket as the date approaches (and mow much)? Are there advertising events that will transiently affect the rate of sales? And so on.

We don't have access to that information, though, so let's just assume, as a first approximation, that the rate of ticket sales is constant. Since sales occur basically at random, they might be best modeled as a [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process) Note that this does not account for the fact that many people will buy more than one ticket, but I don't think that will make much difference for the results; perhaps a real statistician could chime in here. Also: I'm going to discuss the constant-rate Poisson process here but note that since you mentioned the rate is decidedly NOT constant, you could look into variable-rate Poisson processes as a next step.

To model a Poisson process, all you need is the *average* rate of ticket sales. In your example data, sales-per-day are [15, 5, 5, 5, 16], so the average rate is about 9.2 tickets per day. We've already sold 46 tickets, so there are 254 remaining.

From here, it is simple to ask, "Given a rate of 9.2 tpd, what is the probability of selling *less than* 254 tickets in 23 days?" (ignore the fact that you *can't* sell more than 300 tickets). The way to calculate this is with a cumulative distribution function (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for the CDF for a poisson distribution).

On average, we would expect to sell 23 * 9.2 = 211.6 tickets after 23 days, so in the language of probability distributions, the *expectation value* is 211.6. The CDF tells us, "given an expectation value λ, what is the probability of seeing a value <= x". You can do the math yourself or ask scipy to do it for you:

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> scipy.stats.poisson(9.2 * 23).cdf(254-1)
0.99747286634158705
```

So this tells us: **IF** ticket sales can be accurately represented as a Poisson process and **IF** the average rate of ticket sales really is 9.2 tpd, then the probability of at least one ticket being available after 23 more days is 99.7%.

Now let's say someone wants to bring a group of 50 friends and wants to know the probability of getting all 50 tickets if they buy them in 25 days (rephrase the question as "If we expect on average to sell 9.2 * 25 tickets, what is the probability of selling <= (254-50) tickets?"):

```
>>> scipy.stats.poisson(9.2 * 25).cdf(254-50)
0.044301801145630537
```

So the probability of having 50 tickets available after 25 days is about 4%.

Comment: I am familiar with poisson processes, but not with variable rate ones, is that similar to non-homogeneous poisson process? You are correct in saying that I need much more information about my ticket sale distribution, and the truth of the matter is that I don't know. I am assuming that ticket sales are non-linear because each person has a non-linear "assigned date" to buy a ticket, and can not buy it before. But once that date comes, a person may sign up at one of 100s of locations. I had previously thought curve fitting was the best way to go, but perhaps this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, non-homogeneous is what I meant by variable-rate. Curve fitting should be useful to you as a way to model and predict the average rate over time, but it does not tell you anything about probability. The Poisson distribution gets you from rate to probability.

Comment: Is there any way to perhaps use curve fitting in tandem with the poission distribution, perhaps to extrapolate more data points?

Comment: That's exactly what I was suggesting--fit a curve to your data points so you can predict the future rate of ticket sales, then use a non-homogeneous Poisson process to determine the probability based on the predicted rates.

Comment: Oh, got it! Though I have two minor questions regarding implementation 1) I am not familiar with scipy and numpy, but after looking through the documentation, there doesn't seem to be any built in poisson functionality to handle variable cases. I've found some documentation to calculate this manually online, would you suggest doing so? 2) If i use the linear regression to generate more data points via extrapolation, would you suggest balancing between extrapolating too many data points as to skew my average, and choosing too little?